# Mysql Date between for todaydate

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this..

```
S.No Name created_date 
1    N1   2011-01-08
2    N2   2011-01-08
3    N3   2011-01-08
```

I have tried to filter the records by using mysql date between

The query is

```
Select * FROM tbl_name 
WHERE `created_date` >= '2011-01-08' AND `C`.`created_date` <= 2011-01-08
```

I am not getting any results... why ?

Comment: Maybe because we are in 2012?

Comment: ok please consider all the dates are in 2012...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check date formats. Make them same :

```
select * from table 
where date_format(created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(curdate(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: @Teez: Great answer. Unbeliveable...... How you got exact problem without any discussion ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put 2012 instead of 2011? ;)

```
select * from table where created_date = curdate()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need between clause if you just want records of today.

Comment: The customer will enter the fromdate and todate to filter  the records. thats why i need the query by using from date and todate ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE DATE(created_date) BETWEEN '2011-01-08' AND '2011-01-08'
```

Comment: i have tried this .. its not working ... have u tested this ?

Comment: it works fine. I just tested it. The created_date has a DATE column type right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE date(created_date) = '2011-01-08';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use WHERE created_date = '2011-01-08' when you only have one date to select.
If you need to select all posts between data x and date y you can use:

```
WHERE created_date BETWEEN x AND y
```

Answer (score 0):

To find records between two dates use the BETWEEN condition as:

```
    Select * FROM tbl_name 
    WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2011-01-08' AND '2011-01-08'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to always use >= and <

`create_date` >='2011-01-08 12:00' AND `create_date` < '2011-01-09'

same as

`create_date` >='2011-01-08' AND `create_date` < '2011-01-09'

note: >=, <